# ST_Intersects incorrectly returning false in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, intersection

I have a shapefile created from ArcMap that contains about 400 geometry's. I've added this shapefile into PostGIS using the shp2pgsql tool. I am trying to use the ST_Intersects function to determine if a given point, using Lat and Long, is within one of the 400 geometry's. 
I have a point that I know to be within one of the shapes, but ST_Intersects is returning false for this. The record where cocnum equals "MA-500" contains the point Lat: 42.3581, Long: -71.0636.

```
                    SELECT 
                        cocname,
                        cocnum, 
                        geom,           
                        st_intersects(geom, point(-71.0636,42.3581)::geometry)
                    FROM 
                        public.coc
                    WHERE cocnum like 'MA-500'
```

However, I get the following result:

[image: Query Result]

When I create a KML of the geometry using `st_asKml(geom)` and then insert that into google maps, along with the point `google.maps.LatLng(42.3581, -71.0636)` I get the following result:
[image: map]

Any ideas on why ST_Intersects is returning false for this?

Comment: Is your data in WGS84 or something similar (lat/lon) or some other projection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to project your point into your polygon's CRS.  You can use [ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html) to do this.

```
                    SELECT 
                        cocname,
                        cocnum, 
                        geom,           
                        st_intersects(geom,
                            ST_Transform(
                                  ST_GeomFromText('point(-71.0636 42.3581)',4326), 3857))
                    FROM 
                        public.coc
                    WHERE cocnum like 'MA-500'
```

Specifically you're not intersecting because your polygons projection is in meters, so without re-projecting -71.06, 42.35 in meters is a point not far from the equator and prime meridian.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick. If you don't mind me asking, where does 4326 come from. I understand 3857 is the SRID of the shapefile I'm using, so is 4326 the SRID of lat/long points?
Also, I used this same process with other Shapefiles, and I did not need to use ST_Transform. They were based on the GCS_North_American_1983. Is the different Geographic Coordinate System the reason for needing to use ST_Transform or not?

Comment: Yes, 4326 is the EPSG code for WGS84 lat/long.  That's the system that GPS uses, and most of the time when you see coordinates in lat / long they're WGS84 coordinates.  Another common one is NAD83 lat/long which I think is EPGS code 4269.  You'll see it if you use TIGER data directly from the Census folks.  The points you didn't need to use ST_Transform were in the NAD83 lat / long, which is very similar to WGS84.  So that's why it worked without re-projecting your points.

Comment: Ok great, that makes sense. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't get an SRID mismatch error. Perhaps you loaded your polygon data without an SRID.

Comment: Paul, that's exactly what I did. I'm fairly new to GIS, and didn't know what the SRID was, and saw in the shp2pgsql documentation that SRID was optional, I didn't include it.

Comment: best practice is to use ```addgeometrycolumn()``` whenever adding a new column because it registers it with the geometry_columns view in the public schema and tells PostGIS it is there and what the SRID is.

Comment: use addgeometrycolumn() if you're using a version of PostGIS older than 2.0, from 2.0 forward geometry_columns is a view that is autopopulated.  When you add a new geometry column and typemod it to a certain SRID that SRID is picked up by the view automatically.

Comment: @PaulRamsey No. It seems PostGIS isn't verifying the compatibility of the geometries before trying to process. I definitely have SRIDs on all my geometries involved (one is a UTM coordinate system and the other is lat/long), but it just merrily reports that they don't intersect. At least in 2.1.4.